# fabric.js not exporting Canvas with SVG file

Tags: javascript, svg, fabricjs

I'm trying to import an SVG file to my canvas using the fabric.js API.

The rendering works but when I try to export (toSVG()) my canvas I get an empty output.

Here is how I add my SVG file to the canvas (rendering works):

```
fabric.loadSVGFromURL('svg/1000.svg', function(objects, options) {

            //group elements
            var obj = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);

            // put object on the canvas
            canvas.add(obj).renderAll();
});

console.log(canvas.toSVG());
```

Here is the output I get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?><!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
```

Created with Fabric.js 1.4.0

Any help would be most welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fabricSVGFromURL` is asynchronous. So when you call `canvas.toSVG()`, nothing has been added to the canvas yet.

You need to call `canvas.toSVG()` inside the callback.